# Querying multiple tables with the same column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple tables with an account number and a dollar amount.

Table Name: **July Accounts**

```
|   Account Number | Amount |
|------------------|--------|
| 1111111111111111 | $99.00 |
```

Table Name: **August Accounts**

```
|   Account Number | Amount |
|------------------|--------|
| 2222222222222222 | $89.00 |
```

I want my results to display as:

```
|   Account Number |   July | August |
|------------------|--------|--------|
| 1111111111111111 | $99.00 |    -   |
| 2222222222222222 |    -   | $89.00 |
```

So far everything I've tried causes something along the lines of:

```
|   Account Number |   July | August |
|------------------|--------|--------|
| 1111111111111111 | $99.00 | $89.00 |
| 1111111111111111 | $99.00 | $99.00 |
| 1111111111111111 | $89.00 | $89.00 |
| 1111111111111111 | $89.00 | $99.00 |
| 2222222222222222 | $99.00 | $89.00 |
| 2222222222222222 | $99.00 | $99.00 |
| 2222222222222222 | $89.00 | $89.00 |
| 2222222222222222 | $89.00 | $99.00 |
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the question to show what commands have you tried. Btw have you heard of UNION?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use UNION:

```sql
SELECT Account_Number, Amount as July, null as August
FROM July_Accounts

UNION

SELECT Account_Number, null, Amount 
FROM August_Accounts
```